# Incorrect syntax near 'b'

Tags: sql, sql-server, petapoco

I am facing an error while a query is executed:

> Incorrect syntax near 'b'

**Code:**

```
using(var db = new GnpCoreDatabase())
            {
                var basket = db.Query<Basket>
("select p.product_tax,c.shipping_cost FROM dbo.Basket b 
join dbo.CompanyProducts cp b.CompanyProduct_Id = cp.Product_Id 
join dbo.products p on p.Product_Id = cp.Product_Id 
join dbo.Company c on c.company_Id = cp.Company_Id 
where b.Added_by =@0", 1).Select(x => new Basket() {
                Tax = x.Tax,
                ShippingCost = x.ShippingCost,
                IsSuccessfull = true
                }).SingleOrDefault();
                basket.Items = GetAllItems();
                return basket;
            }
```

I don't understand why this error is occurs. I run this query in the database and it produces results.

Comment: Maybe you need to use the keyword `on` in your first `join` line, right before the `b.CompanyProduct_Id`.

Comment: @halfbit: not "maybe" ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `ON` keyword on first `JOIN`:

```
select  p.product_tax,c.shipping_cost 
FROM    dbo.Basket b 
        join dbo.CompanyProducts cp ON b.CompanyProduct_Id = cp.Product_Id 
        join dbo.products p on p.Product_Id = cp.Product_Id 
        join dbo.Company c on c.company_Id = cp.Company_Id 
where b.Added_by =@0
```